# Adding CVXPY abs to optimization problem turns out to be non-DCP

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, cvxpy, disciplined-convex-programming

I have tried to solve an optimization problem using CVXPY library. This problem aims to minimize the distance between a vector of $n$ variables ($\beta$), which can be positive or negative real numbers and another n-dimensional vector ($s$) containing only positive real number, as follows

```py
beta = cp.Variable(n)
problem = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(cp.abs(cp.norm1(beta) - cp.norm1(s))))
```

I tried `cp.norm1(beta) - cp.norm1(s)` and it worked fine, but I want to make sure that the result of the difference between both vectors must be positive. However, when I add `abs`, I got the error saying that "this problem  does not follow DCP rules". I am not sure how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 7):

I think you want `cp.norm1(beta - s)`, with no need for `abs`. This is DCP-compliant.

Taking separate norms of `beta` and `s` doesn't make sense for what you describe.

**Edit**: Note that by using `norm1`, you are minimizing L1 distance. That's fine if that's what you really want. However, distance, when not otherwise qualified, more commonly means L2 (Euclidean) distance, for which you would use `norm` (with default `p`) or `norm2`.